# Is my HDD speed normal for my disk?

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I have a laptop hdd which is relatively new(near 1 year). Last time i felt like it works slower than before. Can someone help me to assess my disk?

my benchmark:

````
Windows System Assessment Tool

Running: Feature Enumeration ''
Run Time 00:00:00.00
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -ran -read'
Run Time 00:00:11.88
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -seq -read'
Run Time 00:00:07.28
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -seq -write'
Run Time 00:00:08.00
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -flush -seq'
Run Time 00:00:05.06
Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -flush -ran'
Run Time 00:00:07.03
Dshow Video Encode Time                      0.00000 s
Dshow Video Decode Time                      0.00000 s
Media Foundation Decode Time                 0.00000 s
Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       1.38 MB/s          3.8
Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   58.04 MB/s          5.6
Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  81.09 MB/s          6.2
Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     1.660 ms          7.2
Latency: 95th Percentile                     24.394 ms          4.2
Latency: Maximum                             115.386 ms          7.6
Average Read Time with Random Writes         8.459 ms          4.9
Total Run Time 00:00:39.38```
````

My disk is - Western Digital Blue 1TB 5400rpm 128MB WD10SPZX 2.5 SATA III Drive is almost full, also i have a game that weights over 400gb

Comment: What is the disk rotation speed? Manufacturers cut costs by using slow hard drives (5,400rpm).

Comment: Knowing what the drive is, & how full, might help.

Comment: Laptop HDDs are pretty borderline rubbish at the best of times, I don't see anything massively bad about your speeds.

Comment: @Tetsujin My disk is - Western Digital Blue 1TB 5400rpm 128MB WD10SPZX 2.5 SATA III
Drive is almost full, also i have a game that weights over 400gb, maybe this is a cause of problem? How can i solve it without deleting?

Comment: @Mokubai thank you for your answer, at least i know that this is not as bad as i thought.

Comment: Being mostly full might mean you are seeking more, and might look worse on benchmarks because you've used up the "good" area at the front of the disk, but it shouldn't kill performance. The way to fix poor HDD performance is with an SSD. A 1TB SSD is [not stupidly expensive these days](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-Internal-Solid-State-MZ-77Q1T0/dp/B089QXQ1TV)